# Sql query prioritising values in php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

column_x of a mySQL database contains values that might exist in a php array.

I want to query the database and prioritise any rows where the value for column_x exists in the PHP array.

My initial idea was to select a column_y that is 1 if column_x exists in the php array and 0 otherwise and then ORDER BY column_y DESC. Is this possible? If so, how do I go about it? Or, is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY column_x IN (list of values) DESC`. When the condition is true, the value is `1`, otherwise it's `0`.

```
$array = array(1, 3, 4, 6);
$str = implode(', ', $array);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourTable
        ORDER BY column_x IN ($str) DESC";
```

If the values come from user input, make sure you sanitize them before inserting into the SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: You need to add additional parameters to `ORDER BY` if you want to control the ordering within the two groups. Otherwise the database orders them arbitrarily.

Comment: Nothing in my code forces the blank rows to the end.

Comment: OK, I've fixed it. Thanks Barmar!